# postfix: postfix-policyd and postgrey

Tags: policyd, postfix

I have postgrey working very good, but I also want the bean-counting features of postfix-policyd to see what's going on the smtp.

is it possible to work with postfix-policyd and postgrey the same time?

Are they disturbing each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both software created with different purpose.

- Postgrey purpose is for do [greylisting](http://projects.puremagic.com/greylisting/), e.g. soft reject whenever client connect on first attempt.
- Policyd primary purpose was adding some advanced policy control for postfix. It can configured to perform various smtp response (REJECT, HOLD, ACCEPT, etc) based on various statistic from sender/recipient/client. But policyd v2 also have abilities to [do greylisting](https://www.policyd.org/content/features) as postgrey do.

As for implementation, postgrey usually placed on `smtpd_recipient_restriction/smtpd_relay_restriction` for earlier rejection. While policyd must placed on both `smtpd_recipient_restriction` and `smtpd_data_restriction` to get full capabilities such as recipient counter.

**Is it possible to work with postfix-policyd and postgrey the same time? Are they disturbing each other?**

Basically YES, both can be installed without disturbing each other. Looks like policyd has greylisting ability, so you can drop the postgrey. If you installed both, ensure that policyd restriction was after postgrey because the policy [doesn't support DUNNO](http://wiki.policyd.org/accesscontrol) for access control